# How to get the correct mimetype of a tmp file

Tags: php

I uploaded a file type spreadsheet trying get its mimetype with `finfo` class passing `tmp_name` key as file name to `finfo::file` method, but it returns a mime unexpected as follows.

```
$fileInfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$fileMimeType = $fileInfo->file($_FILES['tbxFile']['tmp_name']);
echo $fileMimeType;
```

output:

```
"application/octet-stream"
```

I supposed that is the mime type of temporal file... but how to get the "real" mime type of my file without trust in `$_FILE['tbxFile']['size']` ?

Comment: `finfo` *might* need the real name of the file. Or you could try [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) even if it's deprecated to see if it changes anything.